# How to Display Live Photo in View? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, photo, live, display

Load Live Photo File From within the App, What program should write? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will help you
http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-display-live-photos-in-a-view-controller/

Apple gave us a few new classes in iOS 9: PHLivePhoto and PHLivePhotoView. In addition there’s the the PHLivePhotoViewDelegate protocol we can utilise.

Comment: if my Live Photo File ( JPG & MOV ) is inApp, how can i show it in view, thanks!